# D3 V5 Tree link source position is incorrect

Tags: javascript, d3.js, hierarchy

I have been making a tree hierarchy graph, there are two filters, one shows the full hierarchy and one shows just the lineage to a set node in the tree.

When changing to the lineage view, it seems like the source node position of the links is incorrect and keeps its old position.

In this photo below we are displaying the full hierarchy.
[image]

And in this photo below we are displaying just the lineage for one user.
[image]

As you can see, the source position for the links is quite off.

I reduce the graph to the lineage view by reducing the elements that are in the children's array object of each node.

Example of the issue: https://blockbuilder.org/frazboyz/dc5a4f77e9c61acc996f2efc5d00d3cd

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and is this all your code? It feels like your data is being needs to be updated again using `d3.heirarchy()` when you are trying to make the lineage view. Could you create a block on blockbuilder.org?

Comment: So basically all that is happening when I trim the hierarchy view to a lineage view is that I remove all of the children apart from the children required to get to the target and then I update from the root object.

Comment: The problem with that is if you `console.log` your data it will still have the old x, y values for the source. This is why if you create a block with some sample data I could help you better.

Comment: I dont think that should require me to call hierarchy() again right?

Comment: Sure thing, give me 20 minutes.

Comment: Hi, sorry it took a bit longer than expected @Coola. Here you go(Click the change to lineage button): https://blockbuilder.org/frazboyz/dc5a4f77e9c61acc996f2efc5d00d3cd

Comment: The issue is that your `root` data still has `y` values for the deeper nested `children` which are before the Change to Lineage. That is why it is drawing those lines to the original positions. You could write a recursive function to go into the root and change all the x values. I tried to do so but it was not updating the y values but with little success. Alternatively you could take a different approach to getting the path from the root node using the root.path() function like so https://bl.ocks.org/d3indepth/9f6c5dc874d6f21462f308f9e11ebf3c

Comment: I don't quite follow you @Coola I am also not sure how root.path will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug was caused due to me cloning the object and assigning that as the children in Node which changes its object.

Original
https://blockbuilder.org/frazboyz/dc5a4f77e9c61acc996f2efc5d00d3cd

Fixed
https://blockbuilder.org/frazboyz/9d0c834e5c99e1da9481ea6c922cf9ca

See line 216.

Comment: Great. I deleted my answer as your solution is better.